# Better performance in Tomcat startup

Tags: performance, tomcat7

It's first time that I deploy a small app in cloud and my Tomcat is spending an average of 400 MB to startup.

I would like to know if this is normal or if there is something wrong with this number (400MB), or even if there's a way to improve the performance of Tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spending 400MB of RAM? What exactly are you deploying?

Comment: My virtual machine when startup has 139MB used, but when I startup Tomcat the used memory (RAM) go to 540MB. I am deploying a small app (30MB) using Spring MVC, Java, Hibernate, etc. I think there is some setting to tell Tomcat to start with less memory, however I dont know.

Comment: There are a lot of questions regarding the memory settings of Tomcat and Java in general. While searching you must've come across things like `-XX:MaxPermSize and -XX:PermSize`

That being said, *depending on what you do* 400MBs are absolutely possible.

Comment: I create an file named `setenv.sh` with this properties `export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx256M"` to try to reduce de memory but I think is not working. I followed this tip http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Adjusting+Memory+Settings+for+Tomcat